# Butterworth Filter unexpected results

Tags: python, scipy, wav, butterworth

```
def butter_highpass(filename, limit_hz, order=1):
    fs, signal = wavfile.read(filename)
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    high = limit_hz / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, high, btype='highpass', output='ba')
    signal = lfilter(b, a, signal)
    wavfile.write("file.wav", fs, signal)

butter_highpass("example.wav,", 100)
```

I am currently using the butterworth filter in python in order to run a high pass filter over some wav files before processing. So far I have been doing this in audacity but I now need a python implementation

This is a picture of the file I am processing

[image: Wav File Being Processed]

This is the result i expect upon passing the high pass filter at 100hz
[image: Expected Results]

However this is the result that I get ! I cannot work out why this is happening !
[image: Unexpected Result]

Comment: Try `butter(order, limit_hz, btype='highpass', output='ba', fs=fs)`

Comment: same result im afraid :(